# How to change pop-up message while requesting permission in react native for iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, permissions, location, info.plist

[image: permission message]

How can I change location request message i.e: “Allow UAQ Business to use your location”

I have already tried info.plist solution but it is not reflecting in my project, is there something I am missing?

Comment: Which RN version you are using?
Are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions ?

Comment: I am using expo location

Comment: I expect you are using an ejected expo project, right ?
So you are using react-native-permissions as well ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was simple, you just need to build your (react-native) app to reflect pop-up permission message.
This is one of the few things that is reflected only after you build your app.

Comment: just to know, where actually, we should keep our custom message for these permission? I am trying to reflect custom message for android (react-native).Thanks